# Help identify a short story about professor using voodoo doll to prevent the marriage of a much younger woman he loves - by Henry Slesar

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is about a professor of anthropology is in love with the daughter of colleague who went mad. She's half his age. When she announces her plan to marry another, the professor has his servant, a woman from a tropical island, make a voodoo doll in the image of the young woman, counting on her belief in voodoo to make her ill and call off the wedding. As a man of science, the professor does not believe in voodoo, but it turns out to be effective when the servant uses it against him to cause a fatal heart attack.

The story may have originally been published in one of the mystery magazines (Alfred Hitchcock, Ellery Queen).

I'm looking for the original short story or other original source, if there is one.

NOTE: The upvoted answer below cites an episode of the CBS Radio Mystery Theater. I'm seeking the *short story* on which the radio episode is based.

Comment: ["Voodoo Doll" by Henry Slesar](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/3865348) seems a good bet

Comment: It was broadcast as "The Doll". The synopsis looks quite similar; https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTnbP.png

Comment: "Voodoo Doll" aka "Voodoo Doll - $1.98" is a different story.

"The Doll" from the CBS Radio Mystery Theater is the same story, but I'm looking for the original short story (or TV show) from which it was adapted. Thx

Comment: This question as currently phrased seems rather misleading, since it confidently asserts that this radio episode was based on a prior work, when you've admitted in the comments below Valorum's answer that you don't know that. I think the question ought to be rephrased to acknowledge the lack of certainty in that regard.

Comment: @LogicDictates Done, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you're describing '[*The Doll*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTnbP.png)' by Henry Slesar.

> Professor Eric Douglas, an anthropologist, tries not to show his
> jealousy when a young woman, Laura Fletcher, whose father he knew
> well, announces she is going to be married. To stop the ceremony,
> Douglas has his servant, a woman from a tropical island, make a voodoo
> doll in the image of Laura. The doll seems to cast a spell when Laura
> and her fiance go to a justice of the peace, Laura becomes violently
> ill and cannot go through with the marriage.

This story appears to have been an *original production* for the [CBS Radio Mystery Theater](https://www.cbsrmt.com/) show, rather than an adaptation of an earlier written work.

> *"Our mystery drama 'The Doll' was written especially for the Mystery Theatre by Henry Slesar."*

You can listen to it online [here](https://archive.org/details/HimanBrownsMysteryTheaterrevival/1998-11-27-Cbsrmt159-1974-10-10-TheDoll.mp3).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the version in the CBSRMT. However, I doubt that it was an original story, even if it was claimed to be written especially for the RMT.

Comment: @jdscomms - The presenter states that it was written specially for the show, not "adapted specially" for the show or somesuch.

Comment: Yes, I understand. However, this was standard jargon for Slesar's episodes on the RMT, even when they were adapted from previous sources. Take, for instance, Jobo (episode #618) which was based on Slesar's short story of the same name first published in the May, 1963 edition of Amazing Fact & Science Fiction. In the intro to the radio show, EG Marshall says the story was "written especially for the Mystery Theater..." It was not. See here: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56562

Comment: @jdscomms - In that case, I stand to be corrected by a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. I'm not *certain* that there is an earlier story, but most of his episodes were adapted. No luck finding this one yet, though.